# How to parse Python code while keeping string literals exactly as-is?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, literals, string-length

I'm trying to go through all the string literals in Python source code while being able to tell what kind of string literal each one is.

Unfortunately, as you can see in this example, `ast.parse` doesn't work:

```
[node.value.s for node in ast.parse('\'x\'; u\'x\'; b\'x\'; "x"; u"x"; b"x"').body]
```

The output is:

```
['x', 'x', b'x', 'x', 'x', b'x']
```

meaning that I can't distinguish between the `''` and `u''` literals, or the `''` and `""`, etc.

How can I parse Python source code while maintaining the original literal exactly as written?

Is there a built-in way?

Comment: According to the way this `u` prefix is implemented under Python 3 as outlined in [PEP-0414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/), there are effectively no change with the internal representation thus what you want, whether or not the original syntax included a `u` or not, wouldn't be expressed nor communicated back out from the `ast` api.

Comment: @metatoaster: Yeah, but is there a different API? Or do people write their own lexers/parsers for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you're looking for isn't AST-level information. The appropriate level to inspect stuff like this is the token level, and you can use the [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module for that.

The `tokenize` API is pretty awkward - it wants an input that behaves like the `readline` method of a binary file-like object - so you'll need to open files in binary mode, and if you have a string, you'll need to use `encode` and `io.BytesIO` for conversion.

```
import tokenize
token_stream = tokenize.tokenize(input_file.readline)
for token in token_stream:
    if token.type == tokenize.STRING:
        do_whatever_with(token.string)
```

Here's the Python 2 version - the function names are different, and you have to access token information positionally, because you get regular tuples instead of namedtuples:

```
import tokenize
token_stream = tokenize.generate_tokens(input_file.readline)
for token_type, token_string, _, _, _ in token_stream:
    if token_type == tokenize.STRING:
        do_whatever_with(token_string)
```

Comment: Wow thank you!! I'd completely given up hope! For anyone else trying to parse a string literal, try `list(tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(b'\'x\'; u\'x\'; b\'x\'; "x"; u"x"; b"x"').readline))` in Python 3, or `list((lambda items: tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(b'\'x\'; u\'x\'; b\'x\'; "x"; u"x"; b"x"').readline, lambda *args: items.append(args)) and None or items)([]))` in Python 2.

Comment: @Mehrdad: For Python 2, you should use `tokenize.generate_tokens` instead of `tokenize.tokenize`. They renamed the functions in Python 3. (Also, Python 2 gives regular tuples instead of namedtuples, so you have to access elements positionally.)

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that a few seconds ago :) thanks!